# Uses Unit - Out of memory

Tags: delphi

Minha classe TLog herda da classe TBaseModelo:

```
uses
  BaseModelo;

TNFLog = class(TBaseModelo)
...
end;
```

Porém minha classe TBaseModelo precisa ter um atributo do tipo TLog:

```
uses
  Log;

TBaseModelo = class(TInterfacedPersistent)
public
  property Log: TLog read FLog write FLog;
end;
```

Ao indicar o Log na uses do BaseModelo, ao compilar, ocorre o erro "Out of memory".

Pelo que entendi seria um erro cíclico (loop) correto? Como contornar isso?

Answer (score 2):

Para contornar isso voce tem algumas alternativas. A mais usada é declarar ambas na mesma unit, usando **Foward Declaration**

```
TLog = class;

TBaseModelo = class(TInterfacedPersistent)
public
  property Log: TLog read FLog write FLog;
end;

TLog = class(TBaseModelo)
...
end;
```

---

Uma outra alterativa, **e é a que eu recomendo,** é transformar a definição em uma interface

```
unit LogIntf

type
  ILog = interface(IInterface)
  ['{8A897A31-7457-46C3-986A-17786CA11404}']
    procedure Logar(const LogMsg: string);
  end;
```

Daí na class de **TBaseModelo** podes usar:

```
unit BaseModelo;

uses
  LogIntf;

type
    TBaseModelo = class(TInterfacedPersistent)
    private
      FLog: ILog
    public
      property Log: ILog read FLog write FLog;
    end;
```

E na classe de **TLog** podes fazer:

```
uses
  LogIntf, BaseModelo;

type
    TLog = class(TBaseModelo, ILog)
    ...
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre por que você está dando uses numa unit que faz uses da unit que está dando uses nela que por sinal faz uses da unit que também faz uses da unit que está dando uses nela.

Complicado né? Pois é, é assim que o Delphi pensa... Ruim né?

Sugiro que declare **TBaseModelo** e **TLog** na mesma **Unit**. Delphi é um senhor de idade, vá devagar com ele.